# Reverse Queue without parameter

Tags: java, stack, queue, reverse

How would I reverse a queue without having a parameter. I'm trying to copy elements from another queue not in the method and reverse the elements. I have the algorithm but I don't know how to access original queue to copy.

```
public QueueInterface<T> reverseQueue() {
    // TODO 8
    Queue<T> a = new Queue<T>();
    Stack<T> b = new Stack<T>();
    while(!a.isEmpty()){
        b.push(a.dequeue());
    }
    while(!b.isEmpty()){
        a.enqueue(b.pop());
    }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: If queue to reverse is not passed as a *parameter*, then it would likely be in a *field*, or perhaps obtained by making a *method call*, right? I mean, where else would it come from?

Comment: I'm not sure its not a field but I created a shallow copy for the queue. I may not be utilizing it correctly then.

Comment: And how did you envision us answering that? We don't know the context of your question, what class it is in, why there is no parameter, etc. With the given information, I could try *guessing* that it's in a field named `foobar`, but I'd very likely be guessing wrong.

Comment: Meh. Only example I've seen of this uses a parameter which is easier so I wanted to see it done without one.

Comment: So you shot yourself in the foot, and are now wondering why it hurts?

Answer (score 0):

So I added this condition to add elements to a variable temp and run it through a recursive loop but it gives an error message that would be shown if the queue is empty, NoSuchElementException. Would it be easier to create another Queue instead of temp and place elements inside that or some other way.

```
 public QueueInterface<T> reverseQueue() {
    T temp = null;
    Queue<T> a = new Queue<T>();
    if (temp == null) {
        temp = dequeue();
        a.enqueue(temp);
        reversed();
    }
```